# MySQL importing issue

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL server (version - 5.6.35),lot of database are running here and every day am taking full backup using script, 
mysqldump --force --opt --user=$USER --password=$PASSWORD --single-transaction --databases $db > $OUTPUT/`date +%Y%m%d`.$db.sq

backup is done correctly and its size also seems correct only , but when am trying to restore a single DB nothing is happen . nothing is importing and not getting any error , same time some database can import correctly .

Any one can suggest what is issue and how to resolve .

Comment: can you please show you import statement?

Comment: am importing using this command mysql -u root -p databasesname < backup_db.sql;  ## see if am open backup i can see all the table information .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you bring it back:

1. Go into MySQL and do `CREATE DATABASE databasename ;` You should give it the same name it had before it was backed up.
2. At a MySQL prompt type `source /path/to/OUTPUTdate2017Oct13.db.sq ;`

I have only done it from within Linux and do the backup in a similar way to you. Not sure if it works the same from Windows, good luck..